# How to control file caching using apache's .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, browser-cache

I have below block in my htaccess file. Now i realized that there are two config files which i dont want to catch by browsers but other can be cached.

files are **lang.ja** and **config.js** so i thought of using below block

```
 # Dont catch below files

   <FilesMatch "^(lang|config)\.js$">
       ExpiresDefault A0
   </FilesMatch>
```

does any body have any idea how i should add above code in below existing block. i already tried adding above block at starting and ending of below block but it does not work. (it always set js to 6 months expiry.)

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive On

   ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 6 months"
   ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 6 months"
   ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 6 months"
   ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 6 months"
   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2 years"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2 years"
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2 years"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2 years"
   ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2 years"
# Do not cache dynamically generated pages.
   ExpiresByType text/html A1
# Cache all files for a month after access (A).
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 21 days"
 </IfModule>
```

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Mona

Answer (score 0):

Try `FilesMatch` directive without `^` and `$`:

```
<FilesMatch "(lang|config)\.js">
       ExpiresDefault A0
</FilesMatch>
```

- Place above code **at the end** of your .htaccess
- Clear your browser cache or try in a new browser to test this out